PHPUNIT & Symfony 6 - Call to a member function getLocale() on null in Request
I try to test with PHPUNIT my route integration (end to end) but I have a problem with locale value contains in request. I have an error "Call to a member function getLocale() on null".
The creation of my user needs to have the locale value define by LocaleListener:
<?php

namespace App\EventListener;

use App\Entity\User;
use App\Service\LocaleManager;
use Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\Security;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Attribute\AsEventListener;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\RequestEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Twig\Environment;

#[AsEventListener(event: RequestEvent::class, method: 'onKernelRequest', priority: 100)]
readonly class LocaleListener
{
    /**
     * @param Security $security
     * @param LocaleManager $localeManager
     * @param Environment $environment
     */
    public function __construct(
        private Security $security,
        private LocaleManager $localeManager,
        private Environment $environment
    )
    {}

    /**
     * @param RequestEvent $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function onKernelRequest(RequestEvent $event): void
    {
        if (!$event->isMainRequest()) {
            return;
        }

        $request = $event->getRequest();
        /** @var User|UserInterface $user */
        $user = $this->security->getUser();

        if (!is_null($user)) {
            $locale = $user->getLocale();
        } else {
            $locale = $this->localeManager->defineLocaleFromWebBrowser($request->getPreferredLanguage());
        }

        $this->localeManager->setLocale($locale);
        $this->environment->addGlobal(LocaleManager::LOCALE_GLOBAL_VARIABLE_TWIG, $locale);
    }
}

I have a basic LocaleManager service :
<?php

namespace App\Service;

class LocaleManager
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    public const string DEFAULT_LOCALE = 'en';

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    public const string LOCALE_GLOBAL_VARIABLE_TWIG = 'locale';

    /***
     * @var string $locale
     */
    private string $locale;

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLocale(): string
    {
        return $this->locale;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $locale
     * @return self
     */
    public function setLocale(string $locale): static
    {
        $this->locale = $locale;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $locale
     * @return string
     */
    public function defineLocaleFromWebBrowser(string $locale): string
    {
        return $locale === 'fr_FR' ? 'fr' : self::DEFAULT_LOCALE;
    }
}

The WebTestCase :
<?php

namespace App\Tests\Controller;

use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use App\Service\UserManager;
use App\Tests\Trait\FixtureTrait;
use App\Tests\Trait\RestoreExceptionHandlerTrait;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\KernelBrowser;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;
use Symfony\Component\Mailer\Exception\TransportExceptionInterface;
use Twig\Error\LoaderError;
use Twig\Error\RuntimeError;
use Twig\Error\SyntaxError;

class RegistrationControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
    use RestoreExceptionHandlerTrait;
    use FixtureTrait;

    /**
     * @var KernelBrowser $client
     */
    protected KernelBrowser $client;

    protected RequestStack $requestStack;

    /**
     * @var EntityManager $entityManager
     */
    protected EntityManager $entityManager;

    /**
     * @var UserManager $userManager
     */
    protected UserManager $userManager;

    /**
     * @var UserRepository $userRepository
     */
    protected UserRepository $userRepository;

    /**
     * @return void
     */
    public function setUp(): void
    {
        $this->client = static::createClient();
        $this->entityManager = static::getContainer()->get(EntityManagerInterface::class);
        $this->userManager = static::getContainer()->get(UserManager::class);
        $this->userRepository = static::getContainer()->get(UserRepository::class);
    }

    /**
     * @return void
     * @throws TransportExceptionInterface
     * @throws LoaderError
     * @throws RuntimeError
     * @throws SyntaxError
     */
    public function testInvoke(): void
    {
        $crawler = $this->client->request(
            'GET',
            '/sign-up',
            ['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE' => 'fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8']
        );
        $this->client->followRedirects();

        $form = $crawler->selectButton('registration[submit]')->form([
            'registration[email]' => 'user@test.aos-battle-reporter.games',
            'registration[username]' => 'user',
            'registration[password]' => 'plainPassword',
        ]);
        $this->client->submit($form);

        $this->userManager->createUser(
            $form->get('registration[email]')->getValue(),
            $form->get('registration[username]')->getValue(),
            $form->get('registration[password]')->getValue()
        );

        $newUser = $this->userRepository->findOneBy(['username' => 'user']);

        $this->assertEquals('user@test.aos-battle-reporter.games', $newUser->getEmail());
        $this->assertEquals('user', $newUser->getUsername());
        $this->assertNotNull($newUser->getPassword());
    }
}

How to solve this ? It's my first time to test in PHPUNIT with "classic" Symfony project.

Can you double-check that the error "Call to a member function getLocale() on null" really originated from that one line inside LocaleListener or it is actually from another line of codes you are not sharing in your post?
